# Difference between LaTeX and Word in setting font size

Tags: lyx, fontsize

I am working in LyX (compiled with MiKTeX) on Windows. I am a newbie so 
I am wondering how can I manually set the font (like entering in a number
as you would in Microsoft Word).

Comment: I rephrased your title, thinking that this might be more appropriate. Change it if needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Font selection in TeX is a little different from that of MS Word. In LyX, the following choices are available:

- Changing the default font size of the document: Under `Document`>`Settings...`>`Fonts`, you can choose the *Base Size* as being `Default`, `10pt`, `11pt` or `12pt` (Default is `10pt` in most cases). This is similar to the traditional `\documentclass[<fontsize>]{<doc-class>}` selection in LaTeX.

  [image: LyX base font size]
- For changing font size "on the fly" within the text: Select the text, click the *Text Style* button [image: LyX text style] (or `Edit`>`Text Style`>`Customized...`) and choose one of the *Size* options (`Small`, `Normal`, `Large`, etc.). Click *OK* or *Apply* to activate the font selection.

  [image: LyX font size selection]

  Under the *Base Size* of `10pt` / `11pt` / `12pt` (respectively), the following font sizes (or *Text Styles*) hold:

  - `Tiny` (LaTeX's `\tiny`): `5pt` / `6pt` / `6pt`
  - `Smallest` (LaTeX's `\scriptsize`): `7pt` / `8pt` / `8pt`
  - `Smaller` (LaTeX's `\footnotesize`): `8pt` / `9pt` / `10pt`
  - `Small` (LaTeX's `\small`): `9pt` / `10pt` / `10.95pt`
  - `Normal` (LaTeX's `\normalsize`): `10pt` / `10.95pt` / `12pt`
  - `Large` (LaTeX's `\large`): `12pt` / `12pt` / `14.4pt`
  - `Larger` (LaTeX's `\Large`): `14.4pt` / `14.4pt` / `17.28pt`
  - `Largest` (LaTeX's `\LARGE`): `17.28pt`, `17.28pt` / `20.74pt`
  - `Huge` (LaTeX's `\huge`): `20.74pt` / `20.74pt` / `24.88pt`
  - `Huger` (LaTeX's `\Huge`): `24.88pt` / `24.88pt` / `24.88pt`
  - `Increase`: Step one font size up
  - `Decrease`: Step one font size down
  - `Reset`: Same as `Normal`

For specifying and using other font sizes, you will have to include packages that support this or add LaTeX code within your document where you want these changes to take effect. For example, the best way to accomplish this is to use Latin Modern via the [`lmodern` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/lm). Insert this in your *LaTeX Preamble* using

[image]

and then insert the LaTeX code (via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or [image: LyX Insert TeX code]) `\fontsize{40pt}{48pt}\selectfont` where you want it to take effect. `\fontsize{<size>}{<baselineskip>}` sets the font size to `<size>` and the skip from baseline-to-baseline as `<baseline>`. it is usually accepted to have `<baseline>`~`1.2`x`<size>.`Note that this command is considered a *switch*, making all subsequent text that size. If you want to localize the change, you need to use grouping via braces `{`...`}`. For example, the LyX input

[image: LyX input]

yields

[image: LyX output]

A similar approach can be followed using the [`anyfontsize` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/anyfontsize).

Comment: I didn't understand why you put three sizes on each predefined font sizes: Smaller (LaTeX's \footnotesize): 8pt / 9pt / 10pt If I chose Smaller, what size I'm choosing?

Comment: If your document uses a base size of 10pt, then Smaller chooses a size of 8pt. If your document uses a base size of 11pt, then Smaller chooses a size of 9pt. If your document uses a base size of 12pt, then Smaller chooses a size of 10pt.

Comment: @user1367593: See in_wolfram_we_trust's comment. It depends on you base document font size.

Comment: @Werner Could you elaborate a bit about the additional command `\selectfont` that you used to actually insert some text? You didn't "select" any particular font face for the bigger size text, did you. Furthermore, how can I use rather a typewriter or sans serif face using the above `{ \fontsize{}{}  ... }` command?